# Computing the square root of a number using binary search

Tags: binary-search, assembly, numerical-methods

This is implemented in MIPS assembly.

I've hard-coded the initial guess, as I haven't figured out how to allow the user to input a negative or non-negative integer to then display the result back to the user.

```
 # Sqrt.s - Calculates Sqrt of number X by doing a binary search. 

 # Result returning register is $f12                                

.data
x:  .float 123.0
y:  .float 0.0

one: .float 1.0
zero: .float 0.0
two: .float 2.0
precision: .float 0.000000001

counter: .word 0

intro:  .asciiz "Calculates the SQRT of the Input for X in .data 
section!"
inputMSG: .asciiz "Input: "
newLine: .asciiz "\n"
resultMSG: .asciiz "Result: "
errorMSG: .asciiz "ERROR: Input for x < 0 not allowed."


.text
main:
#Initialization
l.s $f0, zero       # zero
l.s $f1, one        # one = 1.0
l.s $f2, two        # two = 2.0
l.s $f3, x          # x
l.s $f4, y          # y = result register
l.s $f18, precision
lw $t1, counter #maintains the count of how many times it has been 
looped and quits after 100 iterations

li $t0, 0   #Set t0 for index of stack
add.s  $f11, $f3, $f0   #set z to x + 0
addi $sp, $sp, 4

#Print intro, with inputMSG + input X
li $v0, 4
la $a0, intro
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, newLine
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, inputMSG
syscall
li $v0, 2
l.s $f12, x
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, newLine
syscall

#-------Algorithm Here---------

#Branch for error if x < 0
c.eq.s  $f3, $f0
bc1t    zeroError
c.lt.s  $f3, $f0
bc1t    zeroError
#-------------------------

loop:
sub.s    $f16, $f11, $f4 #$f16 = z - y

c.eq.s  $f16, $f0       #if difference is equal to zero then answer 
found
bc1t loop3
c.lt.s  $f16, $f18      #if difference is less than precision, end
bc1t loop3
add.s $f13, $f11, $f4    # m = y + z
div.s  $f13, $f13, $f2   # divide m/2

#li $v0, 2
#mov.s $f12, $f13
#syscall
#Print a newline
#la $a0, newLine
#li $v0, 4
#syscall

s.s     $f13, ($sp)     # add midpoint to stack
addi    $sp, $sp, 4     #increment stack by 4
mul.s   $f6, $f13, $f13 #m * m = $f6
sub.s   $f7, $f6, $f3   #subtract m^2 - x

#branch if m^2 - x = 0, then the answer was found
c.eq.s  $f7, $f0
bc1t    loop3

beq $t1, 100, loop3 #quit the program after 100 iterations


#branch if m^2 - x < 0, then jump to loop2
c.lt.s  $f7, $f0
bc1t    loop2

#continue to loop1 if m^2 > 0

loop1:
mov.s $f11, $f13    #set z to m (new upper limit)
addi $t1, $t1, 1     #increment counter
j loop


loop2:
mov.s $f4, $f13 #set y to m (new lower limit)
addi $t1, $t1, 1     #increment counter
j loop


#----------Output Result--------------
loop3:
la $a0, resultMSG
li $v0, 4
syscall
mov.s $f12, $f13  #print result in $f12
li $v0, 2
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall            #exit



#------------Print Error MSG for x < 0-------------
zeroError:
#Print a newline
la $a0, newLine
li $v0, 4
syscall
#Print an Error Here
la $a0, errorMSG
li $v0, 4
syscall

li  $v0, 10
syscall      #exit

.end
```

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't mention this. Yes, it is MIPS. The result is not predetermined.  The value for X under the .data section in random memory is, however. If I change this, the square root currently printed to the screen will change.